# pH of a weak base calculation

Tags: acid-base, ph

Calculate the $\ce{pH}$ of a $100$ $\ce{mL}$ solution containing $0$$.0375$ moles of the weak base, Sodium Benzoate, $\ce{C6H5COONa}$.

> $$\ce{C6H5COO + H2O -> C6H6COO- + OH-}$$

$$\frac{0.0375 ~\mathrm{mol}}{.100~ \mathrm{L}} = 0.375~M$$
$$\ce{pOH} = 0.43$$
$$\ce{pH} = 13.57$$

Is this right? Thank you.

Comment: Benzoate is a weak base, so you can't assume it reacts completely to form $\ce{OH^{-}}$. What's the data you need in this case? Also, your reaction is written a bit incorrectly.

Comment: Would you need Kb?

Answer (score 3):

**Welcome to Chemistry SE!**

To do this specific problem you need to use the $K_{b}$:

$$\ce{\frac{x^{2}}{.375-x}}=K_{b}$$

Finding the $K_{b}$ and solving for x will give you the concentration of $\ce{OH-}$. Remember to take the $-log$ of that and solve for the $pH$.

**Also next time please show some work and take your time to [format](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) these questions so people can try to reply back to you.**