# How to calculate pH?

Tags: analytical-chemistry

Could you please help me or give me any source to understand the calculation of pH in acid and bases both strong and weak ? And pH in salt solutions ?

Comment: https://www.chem.purdue.edu/gchelp/howtosolveit/Equilibrium/Calculating_pHandpOH.htm?

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32769/calculating-ph-in-titration-of-monoprotic-weak-acid-with-strong-base

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/29399/ph-of-a-weak-base-calculation

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35266/calculating-ph-weak-acid-strong-base

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/25203/calculating-vinegar-strength